# Arquillian: how to run a test without packaging/deploy/start/stop tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, jboss-arquillian

I'm wrinting a junit test with @RunWith(Arquillian.class) annotation like described in https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Drone
While writing the test I would like to rin it without wait package war, start tomcat, deploy war, stop tomcat each time.

I run test inside eclipse and I can run tomcat with my web application once and run test multiple times inside the IDE.

Is there any parameter to let Arquillian use an already deployed and running application, without change the source of my test class?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

Arquillian is about **creating deployable** archive and testing it inside true server container.

By the way: if you are looking for ways to speed up your development, then take look at [tomcat remote adapter](http://arquillian.org/modules/arquillian-tomcat-remote-7-container-adapter/). Generally with remote adapter you don't have server startup for each test launch. Just start it manually once.